# Runtime error: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (400x201 and 400x 200)

Tags: python, lstm, summarization

I have created a model using the code below for text summarization

```
class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.attn = nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, hidden_size)  # Ensure correct input and output dimensions

 self.v = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1, bias=False)  # Ensure correct input and output dimensions
def forward(self, hidden, encoder_outputs):
    # Expand hidden to match encoder_outputs's shape
    hidden_expanded = hidden.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, encoder_outputs.size(1), 1)

    # Expand encoder_outputs to have the same number of dimensions as hidden_expanded
    encoder_outputs_expanded = encoder_outputs.unsqueeze(2)

    # Concatenate hidden_expanded and encoder_outputs_expanded along the last dimension
    combined = torch.cat((hidden_expanded, encoder_outputs_expanded), dim=2)
    
    # Debugging: Print out shapes
    print("Shapes:")
    print("hidden_expanded:", hidden_expanded.shape)
    print("encoder_outputs:", encoder_outputs_expanded.shape)

    # Calculate attention scores
    energy = torch.tanh(self.attn(combined))
    attention = self.v(energy).squeeze(2)

    # Apply softmax to get attention weights
    attention_weights = F.softmax(attention, dim=1)

    return attention_weights
```

The code gives the following runtime error

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (400x201 and 400x200)
```

How can this error of the shapes be resolved?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: In other words, it is your responsibility before asking, to [try to check, step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/), what happens when the code runs; and to try to answer: which variables in the program are causing the problem (where is the `400x201` matrix and the `400x200` matrix, that the error message says cannot be multiplied)? Do you understand why the matrices have these shapes? *Should* they have those shapes? If so, why do you think it should be possible to multiply them? If not, what shapes do you think they should have instead, and why?